# How do I keep parentheses of SASS / SCSS mixin?

Tags: css, sass

I'm attempting to make a SCSS mixin for a CSS transform and I want to pass in arguments. However, when using a variable the parentheses of my position value are removed.

How it should look once compiled:

```
transform: translateX(-100px);
```

my mixin:

```
@mixin fadeup ($direction, $value) {
transform: translate#{$direction} ($value);
}
```

when called:

```
@include fadeup(X, 100px);
```

which sadly outputs:

```
transform: translateX 100px;
```

So the parentheses surrounding the 100px value are missing, and so it won't work.

Any ideas how I can keep the parentheses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to me that you could do it with a `unquote` to help maintain the `()`... Something like this should work:

```
@mixin fadeup ($direction, $value) {
  transform: translate#{$direction}unquote("("#{$value}")");
}

.foo {
  @include fadeup(X, 100px);
}

.bar {
  @include fadeup(Y, 100px);
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.foo {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}

.bar {
  transform: translateY(100px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found out a way to do it. I can pass it as a single variable instead:

```
@mixin fadeup ($direction) {
    transform: translate#{$direction};
}

@include fadeup(Y(100px));
```

This will pass the Direction and the value at once in only 1 variable. It's not as readable, but it does work for passing either X or Y as the value + amount.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work using the double unquote but adding pluses before each part of the string:

```
transform:$args+unquote('(') + $value + unquote(')');
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem, and trying with @brbcoding solution not working.
if i write like this:

```
transform: translate#{$direction}unquote("("#{$value}")");
```

the result is :

```
transform: translateX"("100px")";
```

Seem like unquote have problem. so i try this :

```
transform: translate#{$direction}unquote("(")#{$value}unquote(")");
```

and that working perfectly in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I've succeed using parentheses and single quotes:

```
@mixin fadeup ($direction, $value) {
  transform: translate#{$direction}(unquote('(')#{$value}unquote(')'));
}
```