# How do you produce a dynamic transform property with SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to have SCSS render a transform property like `rotate()` with a dynamic variable? To be clear, I'm **NOT** asking how to create a dynamic mixin or variable. I'm asking the appropriate way to interpolate transform properties like `rotate()` and not lose the brackets.

For example, albeit contrived, I'd like to do something like:

```
@mixin dynamic-var($target, $property, $val) {
    .class { 
        $target: $property($val * 10);
    }
}

@include dynamic-var('transform', 'rotate', '36deg');
```

To produce:

```
.class { transform: rotate(360deg); }
```

Comment: I think this feature was declined: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/857

Comment: you can try using variable interpolation, but it can be very glitchy particularly with the use of operators so i advise thorough testing.

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate, however the provided link to solutions is incorrect. I solved my problem by using `#{'#{$property}(#{$val * 10})'}`

Comment: So then a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341431/sass-scss-parentheses-within-mixin